# How to change the size of InkCanvas Strokes in UWP?

Tags: c#, resize, uwp, transform, inkcanvas

I have an unsolved problem with my InkCanvas in my UWP App.

I saved my strokes in a SQLite Database from a InKCanvas with measurements `a*b`. Now I want to display this Strokes on another InkCanvas with different measurements than the InkCanvas with `a*b` (e.g. `a/2 * b/2`).

How can I change the size of my Strokes? I tried to use:

```
var allStrokes = myInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
foreach(var item in allStrokes)
{
    item.PointTransform() = ...// I tried to transform my Strokey with a 3x2 Matrix
                               // But it didn't work. 
}
```

Maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation with matrix worked for me.

I have used the `Matrix3x2.CreateScale` factory method as follows:

```
var strokes = InkDisplay.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
foreach ( var stroke in strokes )
{
    stroke.PointTransform = 
       Matrix3x2.CreateScale( 
          xScale,
          yScale 
       );
}
```

Note, that the `xScale` and `yScale` values represent **relative** scale, which means that when you go from ink canvas of size `X*Y` to ink canvas of size `(X/2)*(Y*2)`, the values would be `xScale = 0.5` and `yScale = 2`.

You can see the sample I have created [on my GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2016/tree/master/InkStrokesResize).

Comment: Thanks you. My roblem was a wrong use of the Matrix. I created it manually und something went wrong. Now all works perfectly with your Code. Especially with the method Matrix3x2.CreateScale(x, y).

Comment: Great, happy it helped :-) . Please, mark my answer so that the question is resolved :-) .